# Sencha nestedList getActiveItem()

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, nested-lists, sencha-touch-2

**I am using this model:**

```
Ext.regModel('ListItem', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'text', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'number', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

**nestedList is:**

```
var nestedList = new Ext.NestedList({
            fullscreen: true,
            title: ivrData.text,
            store: NestedListDemo.music_store,
            getDetailCard: function(item, parent) {
                alert(item.attributes.record.data.number);
            }
        });
```

I am trying to get **.number** property of **activeItem** on a button click.

```
handler : function(btn, evt) {
        var temp = nestedList.getActiveItem();
        alert(temp.number);
        alert(temp.attributes.record.data.number);
}
```

I am able to get the .number property on leafnode by `alert(item.attributes.record.data.number);` but I am getting these error while trying to get .number property for temp:

`alert(temp.number);` prints --> **undefined**

`alert(temp.attributes.record.data.number);` gives error --> "**TypeError: Result of expression 'temp.attributes' [undefined] is not an object**"

Comment: by the way, alert(temp) gives [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got all the property of activenode of nestedlist using code below:

```
nestedList.on('itemtap', function(subList, subIdx, item, e, detailCard) {
    alert(subList.getRecord(item).get('id'));
    alert(subList.getRecord(item).get('name'));
    alert(subList.getRecord(item).get('number'));
});
```

I store this values in local variables.